# Spreadsheet Manipulation Tricks w/ Python's Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-manipulation

I'm giving myself a crash course in using python and pandas for data crunching.  I finally got sick of using spreadsheets and wanted something more flexible than R so I decided to give this a spin.  It's a really slick interface and I'm having a blast playing around with it.  However, in researching different tricks, I've been unable to find just a cheat sheet of basic spreadsheet functions, particularly with regard to adding formulas to new columns in dataframes that reference other columns.

I was wondering if someone might give me the recommended code to accomplish the 6 standard spreadsheet operations below, just so I can get a better idea of how it works.  If you'd like to see a full size rendering of the image just [click here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/Pandas.png)

[image: Pandas spreadsheet example]

If you'd like to see the spreadsheet for yourself, [click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nriNsExtVArXWGoNAZYMklANpvUNwBWbwJGoa9f18Jw/edit?usp=sharing).

I'm already somewhat familiar with adding columns to dataframes, it's mainly the cross-referencing of specific cells that I'm struggling with.  Basically, I'm anticipating the answer loosely looking something like:

```
table['NewColumn']=(table['given_column']+magic-code-that-I-don't-know).astype(float-or-int-or-whatever)
```

If I would do well to use an additional library to accomplish any of these functions, feel free to suggest it.

Comment: This may be of help... [Pandas for Excel Developers](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/bitbucket.org/hrojas/learn-pandas/raw/master/lessons/Pandas%20for%20Excel%20Developers.ipynb)

Comment: @chucklukowski wow, that's just about exactly what I was looking for!  I'll be giving that a read-thru.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you want to be thinking about *vectorized operations on columns* instead of operations on specific cells.

So, for example, if you had a `data` column, and you wanted another column that was the same but with each value multiplied by 3, you could do this in two basic ways. The first is the "cell-by-cell" operation.

```
df['data_prime'] = df['data'].apply(lambda x: 3*x)
```

The second is the vectorized way:

```
df['data_prime'] = df['data'] * 3
```

---

So, column-by-column in your spreadsheet:

**Count** (you can add 1 to the right side if you want it to start at 1 instead of 0):

```
df['count'] = pandas.Series(range(len(df))
```

**Running total**:

```
df['running total'] = df['data'].cumsum()
```

**Difference from a scalar** (set the scalar to a particular value in your df if you want):

```
df['diff'] = scalar - df['data']
```

**Moving average**:

```
df['moving average'] = df['running total'] / df['count'].astype('float')
```

**Basic formula from your spreadsheet**:

I think you have enough to this on your own.

**If statement**:

```
df['new column'] = 0
mask = df['data column'] >= 3
df.loc[mask, 'new column'] = 1
```

Comment: Outstanding tutorial!  Thank you so much; that was extremely helpful.